# To find the expectation of a function of a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent random variables that follow a uniform distribution and $0\leq x_1 \leq k$, $0\leq x_2 \leq k$, where $k$ is a positive constant. Now I want to find the expectation of the function $f_{X_2}(a+bx_1)$ in the region $x_1 \leq a$, i.e., $$ \int_{0}^{a}  f_{X_2}(a+bx_1)f(x_1)dx_1$$

Here is my work: $$\int_{0}^{a}f_{X_2}(a+bx_1)f(x_1)dx_1=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{(a+bk)-(a+b*0)}f(x_1)dx_1\\=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{bk}f(x_1)dx_1=\frac{1}{bk} \frac{a-0}{k-0}=\frac{1}{bk} \frac{a}{k}$$ Is this the right approach?

Thank you!

Comment: What is meant by "the function $f_{X_2}(a+bx_1)$"? What is meant by an expectation "in the region $x_1\leq a$"? Eventually, information about $a$ and $b$ would also be useful (these are given constants? Can they be zero? Are they strictly positive?)

Comment: @Michael for each value of $x_1$, evaluate $f_{X_2}(a+bx_1)$, and then take the integral. "In the region $x_1 \leq a$" means to do the integration for $0 \leq x_1 \leq a$." a and b are given constants that are strictly positive. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael also I use $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2) for a more general case where they follow different distributions, although in the example I provided they follow the same uniform distribution.

Comment: Is $f_{X_2}$ supposed to be the PDF of $X_2$? If so then $$f_{X_2}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{k} & \mbox{ if $0\leq x\leq k$} \\ 0 & \mbox{else}\end{array}\right.$$ and so your integral $\int_0^a f_{X_2}(a+bt) f(t)dt$ seems incorrect. It would need to be of the form $$\int_{c_1}^{c_2} \frac{1}{k}f(t)dt$$

Comment: @ Michael Thank you for your response! $f_{X_2}$ is the PDF of $X_2$. I now realized I made a mistake there. But my new thought process is that, $a+bt$ is a linear function of $t$, which follows a uniform distribution in [0, k]. Therefore, the PDF of $g(t)=a+bt$ is $\frac{1}{b-a}$. So $$\int_{0}^{a}f_{X_2}(a+bt)f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1}{b-a}f(t)dt$$ Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You seem to be mixing concepts.  $g(t)$ is a function of $t$, not a random variable. It does not have a PDF. If you are doing integration then stick to doing integration without throwing in probability. Nobody knows what "expectation in the region" means or what "PDF of $g(t)$" means.  For some reason it seems you want to integrate $\int_0^a f_{X_2}(a+bt)f(t)dt$ for some uknown function $f$ and for $f_{X_2}(t)=(1/k)1_{t \in [0,k]}$. So $$\int_0^a f_{X_2}(a+bt)f(t)dt=(1/k)\int_0^a 1_{a+bt \in [0,k]}f(t)dt$$ You cannot get a numerical answer without knowing $f$.